# How to identify and handle windows form (Open File) loaded from a browser

Tags: c#, selenium

Writing Selenium script to test action linked to a button located on a webpage. Clicking button opens a modal form (windows form) from which user is expected to select a file.

Selenium script handles with the execution of test script up to the moment when the modal form 'File Upload' (File Input) is opened.

Does anyone has any suggestion on how Selenium can recognize opened form, and close it?

Comment: Selenium is used to automate browser actions. Modal windows are **not** browsers. You will need something else. Try [tag:AutoIt].

Comment: Test checks if a button [Import] opens Import form as expected.  As it happens, this form is of a windows form type.
If I understand the negs and first comment; test cannot be implemented and therefore tested?

Comment: @SiKing If you could put this as your answer, I'll accept it. It seems that test will use a mix of both Selenium and AutoIt (AutoITX3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is used to automate browser actions. Modal windows are not browsers. You will need something else.

- [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) is a Windows-only possible solution.
- [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) is another possibility.
- There are others ... do some research.